# Below is the psql code in which I am having syntax error. I am trying to create a trigger function on my test_route database

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nearest_segment_insert()
RETURNS trigger AS
DECLARE id_temp integer;
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.id = NULL THEN
         select test_route.id into id_temp,ST_Distance(test_route.the_geom,NEW.the_geom)
         FROM test_route,
         ORDER BY 2 ASC LIMIT 1;

         UPDATE SET p.edges_id = r.id, p.the_geom = r.the_geom, p.dist_val = r.distance, r.distance = -1 
         FROM test_route r, road_block p,
         WHERE id_temp = r.id ;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
```

I am getting error "syntax error at or near "BEGIN".

Comment: Your code has more than one problem. You should explain the purpose of the trigger, and provide sample data and desired results as tabular text.

Comment: The purpose of trigger is  (on insert) of new point in road_block table. find the closest line from test_route db and set the following parameter in road_block table .

Comment: I am trying to find the nearest line segment to the point using ST_distance()POSTGIS extension. so that I can update the line segement value to -1. So that Dijstras algo doesnot take that line segment into consideration while calculating shortest path.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nearest_segment_insert()
RETURNS trigger AS
DECLARE id_temp integer;
$BODY$
...
```

should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nearest_segment_insert()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE id_temp integer;
...
```

For more information see:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html